How can I pass a generic function to a class in C#
I'm currently working on a Entity Component System (ECS) for a game I'm developing in C# and Monogame.
My GameObject class has a dictionary with all its components, and this method is written to retrieve them.
internal T GetComponent<T> (bool imperative = false) where T : Component 
    {
      string name = typeof(T).Name;
      if (!components.ContainsKey(name))
      {
        if(imperative)
        {
          T newComp = default(T);
          AddComponent(newComp);
          return newComp;
        }
        throw new Exception("Component not found");
      }
      return (T)components[name];
    }

The thing is, that I want to pass this same function (inject this method, if you will) to a component in particular. This is because I want this component to be able to communicate with other components, without passing a reference to the dictionary.
I imagine this component should have something like this
public class UpdaterComponent: Component
{
  internal Func<T> GetComponent; //where T : Component 
  //...
}

And then in the constructor I could pass the function from the GameObject to the Component.
However I have no idea how to write this. I have read about delegates, but I don't want to create a delegate for everytype of Component there is. Is there a clean way to write this?
Thanks!

Why not make GetComponent<T> a method of Component?

GetComponent is a generic method that isn't very generic because you have to know the "type" of the object you want to "communicate with". An inventory of "game objects" that would expose as an "is" or an "as" under further interrogation would be more flexible (IMO); as well as being able to indentify (retrieve): resting; animating; etc. "Communication" implies a bi-directional (entity) relationship which can be implmented in any number of ways.
